# Google Compute Engine Windows RDP Login

Tags: google-compute-engine

I keep getting the error when I try to login to Google Compute Engine Windows Instance. The user is show, I enter the password and I get the error message:

"To log on to this remote computer, you must be granted the Allow log on through Terminal Services right. By default, members of the Remote Desktop Users group have this right. If you are not a member of the Remote Desktop Users group or another group that has this right, or if the Remote Desktop Users group does not have this right, you must be granted this right manually."

Could someone help how to fix this?

Comment: Could you confirm that the user is not the same as the instance name?This is how I reproduced it. Could you try to access as the administrator?By default is disabled so you need to set a password, enable it using the following startup script and reboot the instance:
**key**: _windows-startup-script-cmd_
**value**: _Net user administrator <Password> & Net user administrator /active:yes_

Comment: Actually one of the instance login works even with same instance ID and windows username. 

Some instances dont work even with different instance name and windows username.

I'm following the same steps to create all instances.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely due to an [username equal to the instance name](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310845), or a password too weak to be accepted. GCE doesn't detect invalid users/passwords at instance creation time, resulting in inaccessible instances.

Check instance serial console output [1] to know what is happening. To get windows initial user username and password, use [2] and look for "gce-initial-windows-user" and "gce-initial-windows-password" metadata keys values.

If these values don't work, use [3] to change password during instance start-up and [4] to reboot it, and then try again. All these operations can be performed from the instance detailed view (something like [this](https://console.developers.google.com/project/PROJECT/compute/instancesDetail/zones/ZONE/instances/INSTANCE)) in Developers Console too. Hope this helps.

```
[1] gcloud compute instances get-serial-port-output INSTANCE
[2] gcloud compute instances describe INSTANCE
[3] gcloud compute instances add-metadata INSTANCE --metadata windows-startup-script-cmd="net user USERNAME PASSWORD"
[4] gcloud compute instances reset INSTANCE
```

Comment: The username and password is correct.

Strangely some instances I create work(I'm able to connect through RDP) and some instances give this error. All are same config instances.

I'm doubting it to be some bug with Google Compute Engine Windows Instances.

Comment: I'm using initial windows user(username and password specified while creating instance). 

It doesnt work even once after creating instance. So may not be Windows Updates issue.